# Converting content pages to tt_news (Typo3)

Tags: typo3, tt-news

On a website, I have a section where I put a new page every week. I'd like to convert this to a system using tt_news. How do you suggest me to import the pages (more than 100 pages) to tt_news? Can I do it using a simple SQL query, or should I write a custom PHP script to perform the importation? Is there already an extension that exists that could help me performing this task?

It doesn't really matter to me if I simply build news liked to existing pages, or if I transfer the content of the page to the content of the news. It would be great if I can convert the page title to the news publish date, but I could use the page publishing date as well.

What do you suggest for performing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it via SQL as you mentioned already. Could get tricky if you have multiple content-elements per page that needs to be merged into one tt_news-dataset.

You could also install an extension, that links tt_content-elements with tt_news-records. This way you only have to insert the tt_news-records by traversing the pages and link the content per page to the new tt_news-record. Here are some extension, that link tt_news with content-elements:

- [ttnews_irre](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ttnews_irre)
- [aba_ttnews_content_con](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/aba_ttnews_content_con)

Here is also an extension that could be worth a look: content2news.

Hope this is useful to you.

Best regards,
Peter